# how to retrieve key and value from object search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, javascript-objects

```js
function pageKeywords(searchValue){
  const pageKeywords = {
    "home": "/homepage",
    "about": "/about-us",
    "about us": "/about-us"
  }
  const getInputVal = searchValue;
  
  if (pageKeywords[getInputVal]) {
    console.log(pageKeywords[getInputVal])
    window.location.href = pageKeywords[getInputVal];
  } else {
    console.log('not found')
  }
}

                

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchKeywords").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      pageKeywords($(this).val())
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="searchKeywords">
```

I want to find a page url searching by an input. I have an object that contains keywords and urls. Then when press enter it will do a check, if the keywords are the same or exist, it will display the url, if not it will display not found.

So for example in the input I type "home", when I enter it will display the url "/homepage" because the keywords are exist, if I type "contact" it will show not found because the keywords doesn't exist.

I've made the code like below but why not found appear too?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchKeywords").on("keypress", function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){   
      const map = {
        "home" : "/homepage",
        "about" : "/about-us"
      }

      const searchVal = $("#searchKeywords").val()

      Object.entries(map).map((k,v) => {
        if(searchVal == k[0]){
          console.log(k[1])
        }else{
          console.log("not found")
        }
      });
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="searchKeywords">
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods). Note that you attempt using those of [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods); you seem to be confusing plain Objects with Arrays. Have you tried `pageKeywords[$(this).val()]` and `pageKeywords.hasOwnProperty($(this).val())`?

Comment: That `map()` will throw an error in browser dev tools console . You didn't mention any error. The error message can also be used to do a web search and would probably give you a big clue

Comment: i've edit my description and code above @SebastianSimon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `pageKeywords` is an object. So you can directly retrieve the key, but need not to use map and Object.entries. Also note You can initialise the object outside the keypress event listener & prefer using `===` instead of `==`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  const pageKeywords = {
    "home": "/homepage",
    "about": "/about-us"
  }

  $("#searchKeywords").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      const getInputVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      if (pageKeywords[getInputVal]) {
        console.log(pageKeywords[getInputVal])
      } else {
        console.log('not found')
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="searchKeywords">
```